# Where to buy a type-59?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I often see some type-59 in tier 6-9 games but I don't see it in any tech tree.
I Would like to buy one because it seems to be very strong. Do I need to buy premium for a certain ammount of time? Do I need to buy something else? Is it a special tank or a more-than-premium tank?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the type 59 is not available from the standard gift store.

However, during special events or certain periods it's put in the store again temporarily, so if you keep following the world of tanks news page you should be able to pick it up eventually.

Another less sure way to pick one up is to join the competitions Wargaming sometimes organizes, the type 59 is often one of the prizes.

Comment: Could you put the link to the world of tanks news page please? Thanks and great answer!

Comment: http://worldoftanks.eu/news/ if you're on a European server, http://worldoftanks.com/news/ for the US

Comment: There's currently a competition for the EU server where you can win a Type 59: http://worldoftanks.eu/news/6496-2nd-anniversary-birthday-card-contest/

Comment: Well, I play on the US server I think. I'm not sure though, I never checked this. I'm planing to buy a T34 or a Löwe. Would you like to tell me what you think of them?

Comment: I have never played either of them, but when fighting one I would rather face a Lowe then a T34. In my opinion in the hands of an experienced player, the T34 is more deadly and difficult to defeat. The T34 has a weak hull, but a very strong turret, a player who can park it behind cover for it's hull with a good firing positions is nearly impossible to kill. The Lowe on the other hand is a good overall tank, but easier to kill, but still would probably be the better choice for an average player.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. They just removed it. I was not sure it was possible. Now I'm disapointed.

source: http://tagn.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/type-59-being-pulled-from-the-world-of-tanks-store/

Answer (score 0):

You can, [as of version 8.8](http://worldoftanks.eu/en/content/guide/release-notes/release-notes-88/), buy a T-34-3 which is basically a new version of the removed Type 59 - it's not as good as the original though.